# How I can add some horizontal padding to x-axis tick values in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

Trying to solve this problem for several hours, but have not found any solutions.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SNo9.png)

For x-axis this adds only vertical padding. But how I can move tick values horizontally to the left?

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                padding: -15
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `offset: true` on the x-axis as follows:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      offset: true
    }]
  }
}
```

> [`offset`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration): If `true`, extra space is added to the both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area. This is set to `true` for a bar chart by default.

Comment: Already tried, and it does not work correctly for me.
screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiabK.png